# Integrating html, css, and python

Tags: python, html, css, web-applications

I am building a web application that contains calculators for various industries. I am using html and css for the layout(color, size, etc). However, the core funtionality like arithmetic operations will be done using pure python programming and not javascript. So I will have html, css, and python files. Question is - how can I link my python file to html?

Comment: Just a heads up as well, anything you can do in python is 100% possible in javascript and its libraries. In my experience, it is much easier to re-work your python into javascript than it would be to put it on the backend with a separate framework. But, if you were looking for a python framework, I would recommend something like Flask or Django. There are a ton all over the internet. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use python to run in the browser on the client's machine in the same way as JS, just because browsers are built to execute JS and not Python. However if all you want to do in the python is backend work, that is definitely possible.

I would suggest looking at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) a popular python web framework that is quite easy to get started with.

Comment: I see. So how can I do that without using any framework such as django and flask? Just pure python. Dropbox was written purely in python no html and css I believe...

Comment: Dropbox's backend was python before they moved to Go, however their frontend was originally written in javascript, and later coffeescript. Also, I don't know that they didn't use a framework, and if that is true, they would have basically built a framework themselves. This is not a task which is useful for a beginner trying to create a simple web app. You would be best off looking at popular python frameworks like django or flask. Why don't you want to use a framework?

Comment: Frameworks are certainly helpful. However, I personally do not want my work to be so dependant on frameworks that can easily change in a year or two. I want 100% flexibility and control of my program. It may take a little longer but at least I can feel good that my entire program was written from scratch and I have 100% control over it.

Answer (score 2):

I could think of two easy ways right away, either stick to a solid framework, like `django`. Or you can make python scripts that manipulate `.js` files since text manipulation is easy and fun in python. But there are many more possibilities, like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and more.

Comment: I see. So how can I do that without using any framework such as django and flask? Just pure python.

Comment: let me prototype something quick and dirty. will be posting link here.

Comment: Awesome. Otherwise, I dont mind writing it in JavaScript then.

Answer (score 0):

If the only function you want from the python(and the server side in general) is the calculation, I would suggest taking a serverless structure. It's simpler, less low-level work, easier to upgrade and scalable.

An example of build one with python is with [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) (AWS lambda)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Brython

> Brython is designed to replace Javascript as the scripting language for the Web. As such, it is a Python 3 implementation (you can take it for a test drive through a web console), adapted to the HTML5 environment, that is to say with an interface to the DOM objects and events.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm two months late, but if you're still set to using Python with your HTML/CSS website, it is completely doable.

However, as the previous answer mentioned, if it is only for calculations and light functionality, you're better off using javascript.
Please refer to this [link](http://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-web-application-using-flask-in-python-3) to get an idea on how to integrate python using Flask with your HTML website.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use flask as a backend as big platforms such as youtube use Django(which is a python framework). And I am sure that js is powerful that it can handle arithmetic operations you can check the webs out for that. But if you want to use flask it is very easy here is the basic structure

```html
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pyautogui
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


app.run()
```

Keep in mind that python is limited to things and it would be hard to publish a website with python as backend